# Having problems joining UV sphere to pmx model

Tags: modeling

I am a newbie. I am working on modding a pre-existing pmx low poly figure model (modding is allowed in license). I am having trouble joining the figure and a UV sphere. I want the sphere added as an earring. No matter how I try, I cannot manage to join the sphere to the figure and have it move with the head. I'm sure this is something simple, but even boolean won't work.

Comment: Have you tried selecting the UV sphere then Shift-selecting the figure in Object mode and hitting Ctrl-P > Parent to Object (Keep Transform) ? (I assume parenting works in the software you'll use it in?)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.